# Skobbler & Annotation animations

Tags: android, skmaps

We are looking to see what options there are in providing additional animations to annotations on Skobbler maps.

What we are specifically looking for is an animation which cycles - e.g. a bouncing pin which you can achieve with Google maps.

Is it possible to achieve this using the 'out of the box' classes, or do I have to create some custom view?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the SKAnimationSettings.

```
SKAnnotation ska = new SKAnnotation(1);
map.addAnnotation(ska, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);
```

Comment: Thanks. Whilst this does have an animation action to it, its a one off animation i.e. it drops into position and thats it. What we are looking for is more of an animation which, for example, bounces the pin. If you imagine rolling through a search results list and you want the current item in the list to be animated on the map then something like a continuous bounce or glow effect makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @jamie Ah ok I see what you were looking for now. It may be difficult to implement because much of SKMaps is written natively. Good luck though.